# Profile picture requires reload to change

Tags: caching, laravel, laravel-4, upload

I'm having problem with my PHP application. People can upload a profile photo to show on their profile page. The problem is that once the photo is uploaded you need to refresh the page in order for the photo to change.

I'm redirecting the user back (after the upload succeeded) to the previous page with Laravel's redirect function, like so:

```
return Redirect::to("/user/". $id . "/edit");
```

I assume the photo is saved in the cache and needs to be refreshed? But that would be weird because when I redirect it actually "refreshes" the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you reupload the picture are you USING PUT or PATCH? To replace the old image location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cache-bust the image by attaching a random variable to the image url:

[Cache Busting Files](http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=275)

Comment: I will check this out. Why would this work by the way? Adding a random string behind the img url?

Comment: The image url is used to retrieve the image from the cache. When a variable is attached/changed in the url, it causes the browser to have to re-fetch/cache the image based on the updated url.